# Send mail to javamail (or ftpmail?) and save attachment

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I have been searching for a solution for my problem for a while now.

It work to send mail through javamail, and get an attachment to save. But the problem is that I cant get swedish letters like 'åäö' to show. The file is saved in ISO-Latin-1. (Filename is like "ISO-8859-1HwhajkAWJKHWo..."). I have tried to decode it and every solution that I've found searching.

But it wont work, doesn't matter how much I try, it wont work. Anyone have a similar problem?

And then I was thinking is it possible to send an email to ftpmail(?) and using a java program to catch the attachment in the file and save it. With all the letters copied correctly (åäö).

Or does anyone have another solution to fix this? Send an email to a server who will look through the mail and if it got attachment, save it.

Answer (score 0):

Really, javax.mail works fine with UTF-8. You have to set it for subject, content and text attachments.

```
    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
    message.setSubject(subject, "UTF-8");
    message.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=UTF-8");
    message.setText(body, "UTF-8");
```